# correct or optimal way to configure eclipse project dependecies

Tags: java, eclipse, dependencies

Hi:  I realize my question is probably going to sound vague and probably not specific, but I am grasping for a general direction to go.

I was tasked with coding a POC that in general would make some REST calls from a Java client and compare the results.  Not wanting to re-invent the wheel I asked if there was some existing code that already had some http posting functions I could make use of.  I was directed to a particular java file that was a part of a much larger project and in system of interrelated projects.

My project is a java application project in eclipse and I imported the java file mentioned above with it's project as a peer gradle project into my workspace.  This introduced a whole lot of errors that are caused by missing dependencies.  The file, it's project and it's related projects all compile when they're all imported into another workspace as gradle projects.

Was importing the file and it's project as a gradle project at the same level as my POC/testing code not the correct way to make use of existing code?  The missing dependent jars can all be found deep within cache directories referenced in the External jar/Libraries section of project properties but I don't think harvesting them and getting them to a place that my class path would include is the correct fix.

Isn't there a correct or optimal way to have arranged these items to have avoided this state?

Thanks for any/all assistance you may provide.